# Calculating days or common time span from a data set including months, years, days, and weeks in R

Tags: r

I have a data set from a survey that asks how long someone has been practicing a program.  My problem is, the users were allowed to type a number and then pick days, months, weeks, or years from a dropdown.  I designed it this way to avoid dirty data but now have this question: How can I calculate these all into days (or some type of time span)?  I'm thinking I will need to use a CASE WHEN statement, but would appreciate any tips and am wondering if there is already a function in R to do something similar.

Here is a link to my results: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1QhZrObecugV5ovWWrMxrZpi7Boikp21hE41SWhVRU1A/edit?usp=sharing

My goal is to plot how many pounds lost over how much time.  I can worry about the other variables later.

Thanks and please be gentle- I am a newb at R.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you are looking for? This uses the `dplyr` package.

```
dt$days <- case_when(
            dt$c == "Day(s)"  ~ as.integer(dt$timespan),
            dt$c == "Week(s)"  ~ as.integer(dt$timespan * 7),
            dt$c == "Month(s)"  ~ as.integer(dt$timespan * 30),
            dt$c == "Year(s)"  ~ as.integer(dt$timespan * 365),
            )
```

This is the set i used to reproduce:

```
str(dt)
'data.frame':   14 obs. of  6 variables:
 $ A       : Factor w/ 14 levels "10/19/2018 10:00:50",..: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
 $ B       : num  34 6.6 60 80 30 18 45 17 31 16 ...
 $ timespan: int  4 7 22 18 24 11 3 4 5 4 ...
 $ c       : Factor w/ 2 levels "Month(s)","Week(s)": 1 2 2 1 2 2 1 2 1 2 ...
 $ d       : Factor w/ 5 levels "Dirty","Dirty, LCHF",..: 1 4 5 3 1 1 3 5 4 4 ...
 $ days    : int  120 49 154 540 168 77 90 28 150 28 ...
```

Answer (score 0):

here's a quick solution! I just took your google sheets and made a quick csv in excel and read it in. I changed the time number to the variable "Number" and the Month(s), Week(s) to the variable "Time Unit". Then I created a quick new category and then multiplied using mutate()

```
library(dplyr)
d <- read.csv("/pathtofile/Qdata.csv", header=T, stringsAsFactors=FALSE, na.strings=c("","NA"))

d$Time.num <- NA
d$Time.num[(d$Time.Unit == "Month(s)")] <- 30
d$Time.num[(d$Time.Unit == "Week(s)")] <- 7

d <- d %>% mutate(interval.days = Time.num *Number)
```

That provided a good output by count. Hope that helps!

Edit: 
SO, since it's just two options we can just do a simple if_else() here.

I think this is more elegant:

```
library(dplyr)
d <- read.csv("../LithuimsNPS/sNPSData/Qdata.csv", header=T, stringsAsFactors=FALSE, na.strings=c("","NA"))

d <- d %>% mutate(Time.num2 =if_else(Time.Unit== "Month(s)", 30, 7))
```

Comment: Thank you!  I did the same and am getting NA in the Time.num column.

Comment: Hey Holly Jolly. I ran it again and am still getting a clean output. I would check to make sure you have the names correct in the Time.Unit column. You can also change the 
d$Time.num <- NA to d$Time.num <- 0 and see if that helps.

Comment: Ah, here is a better solution, we can if else as it is either Months or Weeks. So let's just use If_else().

library(dplyr)
d <- read.csv("../LithuimsNPS/sNPSData/Qdata.csv", header=T, stringsAsFactors=FALSE, na.strings=c("","NA"))

d <- d %>% mutate(Time.num2 =if_else(Time.Unit== "Month(s)", 30, 7))